# "Refilling" items in a chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Let's say that I have 3 chests, each containing one of these items:

1. A full set of armour (Leather, White Stained)
2. A Named Lever
3. A Named and Enchanted (Unbreakable) Bow.

How can I "restock" these items to the chests if someone was to remove them? I have a feeling it might involve a trapped chest and some command blocks....

Comment: Umm... what? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: How does it involve redstone?

Comment: @Ben If a player takes a certain item from a chest, I want a command block or something to put another one of the same item "back into" the chest.

Comment: There's definitely a way to use nbt in commands to refill a chest. I don't remember the details off the top of my head.

Comment: simple, have a sample chest copied to the "refilling" chest's location, then all of the items in the chest would be refiled every time the chest is copied and pasted to the existing chest's spot